# What's the correct way to use PreparedStatement in java?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

Specifically if I have three queries should I do

```
PreparedStatement singleQuery ...
```

and "share" the one object. Or should I do

```
PreparedStatement query1 ...
PreparedStatement query2 ...
PreparedStatement query3 ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how different the three queries are. If they are the same query but with different arguments then use a single `PreparedStatement` and set the arguments each time. If they are essentially three different queries (e.g. a select followed by an update) then you'll need three different `PreparedStatement`s.

For example, if the SQL for all three is of the form `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = something` then a single statement is fine.

If the first query is `SELECT name FROM customers WHERE id = ?` and the second is `SELECT price FROM products WHERE id = ?` then you're gonna need different objects.

Comment: I think it's implied in the question that the 3 queries can use the same SQL (with different parameter values).

Comment: It's implied by the fact that `PreparedStatement singleQuery ...` is even an option to begin with!

Answer (score 3):

If the three queries use the same SQL, reuse the same object.

If not, have three separate objects.

Do not share the same object across multiple threads.

Comment: I think it's implied in the question that the 3 queries can use the same SQL (with different parameter values).

Comment: +1 for the "do not share the same object across multiple threads". But how to do it in this case ? I was thinking about crafting n PreparedStatement objects and using them from a  stack. There will be n threads, each popping from and pushing back to the stack the PreparedStatements when done with their result sets.

Comment: @Thilo: I'll be starting with 10, but will probably increase them. So changed the mechanism to have 10 PreparedStatements at hand of each query type there is.

Comment: actually, if I am not mistaken, there isn't a given limit of PreparedStatements exectuing on a connection. If this is the case then my doing as in previous comment would actually deprive the DB connections of some traffic.

Comment: I'd not build pooled PreparedStatements. Just make (and dispose) new ones as needed within the thread (use a Connection pool, though). If you really perceive this as a performance problem (investigate!), see if your driver offers statement caching.

Answer (score 2):

If the queries are different, you probably need separate PreparedStatement s but if the different queries can be handled by one parameterized query, you should probably go that route.

Answer (score 1):

Use a single parameterized query and call it 3 times, each time binding the new parameter values. If your db supports caching of prepared statements, you'll get better performance because the actual query will only need to be compiled once by the RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you would use a separate PreparedStatement object for each query; that way you could keep them around to re-use, potentially saving preparation overhead.

If you aren't planning to re-use your statements, though, it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: how can you change a prepared statement once it was prepared? I don't think this is possible.

Comment: How does using a separate `PreparedStatement` for each query promote re-use? Seems like just the opposite to me...

Comment: @Asaph I'm assuming the three queries are distinct queries, not the same query with different parameters.  If they are distinct queries, you can keep them around to use again next time required

Answer (score 0):

You can use it any way, there is NO performance issue as long as you open the Prepared statement and Close the prepared Statements appropriately.

Suppose if you use the single prepared Statements, Make sure if you are going to use that one for the second one, the required variables to be provided appropriately.